# Determine if another build is queued in TFS before executing build task

Tags: tfs, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

We run an environment were multiple features are divided into branches.  Those branches are configured to a channel in Octopus Deploy.

I would like to see if there is a way to check in a build definition if another build is queued for a branch.

For context - I have a Octopus Deploy step as the last step in our build definition.  To deploy the app - it takes approximately 10 minutes.  Our build process is also about 10 minutes (it is a big application).

When a team working on one feature checks in - we end up with 2 and 3 builds queued and waiting for each check-in and build to complete.

What I would like to do is have the deploy task run only if there is NOT another build queued for the same branch.  This would ensure we don't waste 30 minutes of unnecessary deployments and only deploy the latest code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being easier than I thought - but not exactly what I tried to do in the question.

The Octopus Create Release Task for TFS and VSTS has an option to "Show Deployment Progress".  Checking this causes the build definition to wait - periodically receiving feedback from Octopus through the Octo.exe tool.

The deployment for this is actually a wrapper for several deployments (15 separate projects) - so it would take a long time.

Unchecking this option causes TFS to not wait - but send the create release / deploy command to Octopus.

Now this didn't solve my initial question - but Tingting0929-MFST did help me out in that I explored using the TFS Rest API.  I wrote a PS script the effectively did what I asked - not deploy if there was a another build queued up for the same branch.  I got it working - but it introduced a different problem in that the release notes from TFS and associated changesets / work items were getting swallowed in between releases.

In other words if three checkins came in fairly close separation, the last one would get deployed.  Octopus would show only the release notes for last deployment and not the first two.

For those using Octopus Deploy in a feature branch set-up (one project deploying to multiple channels) - this is an option to get you the Continuous Deployment for each channel (branch).

Answer (score 1):

What type of build do you use? XAML build or Vnext build. It seems that you use the CI trigger in your build definition, so it will trigger a build each time you do a check in.

**VNext build:**

You could select the **Batch changes** checkbox. According to [this document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers),

> If you select this option, when a build is running, the system waits until the build is completed and then queues another build of all changes that have not yet been built.

[image]

This will combin the changes into one build when you have a lot build queued.

**XAML build:**

In the build definition, you could use the **Rolling builds** trigger. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh190718%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#reason_batched_ci) has the same function like the Batch changes mentioned above.

**Note:**

You also could use [this REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#for-a-build-definition) to get if there're builds of a build definition that are queued.

```
Http method: Get  
http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamprojectName/_apis/build/builds?definitions=10&statusFilter=notStarted&api-version=2.0
```